# Does sfdisk under Linux have a preset default for sector size?

Tags: linux, partition

I'm using sfdisk as part of a process to copy one drive to another. From what I can find, it looks like it defaults to a 512 byte sector size, but I don't see anything that clearly states that as a given. I'm reading the partition table (obtained with '-d') from one drive and writing it to another. I'm not specifying anything other than raw numbers for partition sizes, like this:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0xe5e884c6
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        8192, size=      524288, type=e, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=      532480, size=   245227520, type=83
```

Will sfdisk use a default sector size of 512 bytes when I write this to a new device? Is there anything else that can influence that, such as device size? (In the man page, the sector size isn't addressed, at least not clearly.)

Comment: sfdisk will use the sector size of the device. This is standard behaviour. If sector sizes differ, I'd take another approach to avoid hassles.

Comment: @stoney How do I find the sector size of a device? Is that hardwired into the type of device?

Comment: If you mean the model of the device with 'type of device', yes. `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/hw_sector_size` shows it.

Comment: @stoney Thank you! If you want to put that together as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sector size of a device with `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` or with `/sys/block/sdX/queue/hw_sector_size`.

The sector size is device-dependant.